# Selecting records on base of first character

Tags: sed, grep

I have a file which contains the following records

```
+aaaa
+bbbb
 cccc-123
-dddd
 eeee+789
-fff+456
 ggg
```

Now I want to keep only the records if the first character is a "+" or "-" sign
so the (new) file should look like this

```
+aaaa
+bbbb
-dddd 
-fff+456
```

Can this be done via a grep or sed command ?

Comment: Could you please do add 3 simple things in your question. 1st- Clear sample of input, 2nd- clear sample of output and 3rd- your tried commands/code, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
grep '^\[+-\]' myfile.txt
```

or

```
grep '^[+-]' myfile.txt
```

Depending on your flavour of grep

Comment: It should be `grep '^[+-]' myfile.txt` ?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^[+-]/!d' file
```

or:

```
sed -n '/^[+-]/p' file
```

In the first solution: if the first character of the line is not `+` or `-` delete the line.

In the second solution: if the first character of the line is `+` or `-` print it.